# Is there a dataset that can predict duration to complete a task using task description?

Tags: tensorflow, prediction

I am working on a problem where the task is to predict how long will it take to complete a given task using just the description as a feature set. The description is something like "pick up X and place at y".
Currently what I have done is vectorized the descriptions using tensorflow feature embedding: a categorical column with vocabulary list, and an embedding column with dimensions set to 100.

Since the dataset I have only consists of 6 rows, and my client wants to see if the same model can be trained on a larger dataset I am looking for something similar. Therefore, please advise, also am I doing this the right way ?.

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. I think the scope of the problem is way too broad: a "task" is not a formal concept, "wash up the dishes" can be a 5 mn task or a 3 hours task if it's at a busy restaurant. The scope must clearly define which specific types of tasks are valid and in which specific context, otherwise I don't think this can work.

Comment: Sorry about that but that is the problem I am working with. The dataset is way to vague at this stage. The task is normally something like "Pick up an item and put it on something", "Accept delivery on bay 413", etc. There is no complete list generally a list of tasks will be built as the project progresses. What I am confused about is that its not a complete classification problem nor a NLP problem its something in the middle. We can assume that over time there will be a list of about 20 different tasks with the time completion as Y.

Comment: Do these 20 different tasks each have a fixed duration, or are they like different types of task for example "travel from X to Y" where X and Y are different every time? In the former case it's just a matter of predicting the right task out of 20 (simple text classification), whereas in the latter case it's classification followed by 20 different problems for estimating the time.

Comment: Over time it will grow but presumably X and Y will be from a fixed list. So there will be a fixed list of tasks that will be built over time and once every possibility is built then it wont change. The task at hand is to recommend the scheduler before hand what will be the expected completion given the historical data.

Comment: If I understand correctly, eventually you will have a list of task ids, each task id assumed to have a fixed duration. This means that the goal is only to map a task to its average duration. As far as I can tell there is no ML in this. The only part possibly involving ML is identifying the task id from the task description in case task descriptions have variations.